# I want that a discord bot only send direct messages if the person put the command in the server not in the dm of the bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Im doing a bot of discord and it send a dm but I only want that the bot send the dm when the person put the command in the server no in the dm. I mean I want that my bot doesn't respond's the person that put the command in the dm of the bot. If someone can help me I will be very thankful.

Comment: Please, take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can block the bot from responding to commands in its dms by checking if the channel type is direct message (dm) if that happens just simply return and the bot won't respond

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
});
```